# Django --- ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, django

I am using this view function to serve files for downloading ,

```
from django.http import FileResponse
def sendFiles(request): 
    filename = request.GET['filename']
    pathToFile = os.path.join(filesDir, filename)
    response = FileResponse(open(pathToFile, 'rb'))

    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
    response[
        'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(pathToFile)
    # HttpResponse(open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'LYYDownloaderServer.log'), 'r'), content_type='text/plain')
    return response
```

after pasting  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/VideoParser/files/?filename=Git-2.8.4-32-bit.exe` to the browser address bar and Enter , then the file begin to download, when I pause the downloading , then the server console output the following exception , anyone can figure out what's wrong here?
Tested on Win10 using Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.9

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54276)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 92, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 628, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 99, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 684, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\iMath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Have you tried [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse)?

Comment: @RaviKumar FileResponse is a subclass of StreamingHttpResponse